# How to convert binary array to decimal in C

Tags: arrays, c, binary, decimal

I am trying to convert a binary array to decimal
Here is what i have to convert, binTodec[8] = {1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1}

I have started with
for(int i=0; i<8; i++)

Is there anybody that can help me

Comment: What do you need help with? The conversion logic? coding the logic itself? Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

One method is to calculate from the most significant bit to the least significant bit.

If binTodec[0] is the most significant bit in binary number :
The decimal number is
`1` * 2^7 + `1` * 2^6 + `1` * 2^5 + `1` * 2^4 + `0` * 2^3 + `0` * 2^2 + `1` * 2^1 + `1` * 2^0
= 243
The implemented code would be

```c
int binTodec[8] = {1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1};
int result = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    result *= 2;
    result += binTodec[i];
}
printf("%d\n", result);
```

On the other hand, if binTodec[0] is the least significant bit in binary number :
The decimal number is
`1` * 2^0 + `1` * 2^1 + `1` * 2^2 + `1` * 2^3 + `0` * 2^4 + `0` * 2^5 + `1` * 2^6 + `1` * 2^7
= 207

The implemented code would be

```c
int binTodec[8] = {1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1};
int result = 0;

for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    result *= 2;
    result += binTodec[i];
}
printf("%d\n", result);
```

Comment: A perfect use case for the *downto* operator: `for (int i = 8; i --> 0;) { ... }`

Comment: Is that newly invented "downto" operator intented to confuse people learning C?

Comment: What if I rewrite the default example to `for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)`, and add the downto example at the end as additional footnote?

Comment: Using `-->` is not a problem. But calling is an operator confuses people. Beginners might believe that it actually is an operator. Which it is not. It is just a post decrement operator followed by a larger than operator

Comment: It makes sense. I will revert my answer to the original version. Because it has a similar pattern of the other case, and it's easier to understand. Explaining the combination of 2 operators would be a further topic of this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned toUnsigned(const int *arr, size_t size)
{
    unsigned result = 0;

    if(arr && size)
    {
        while(size--)
        {
            result *= 2;
            result += !!*arr++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```